# Running Web Services on different ports while allowing web site to use port 80 and 443

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6, windows-server-2003

Is it possible to have a web service run on a dedicated port while still allowing the web site to use port 80 and 443?

I would actually like to run different web services from the same site on different ports if this could be done.

I have been looking at seperate App Pools or other possibilities, not sure if there was a tried and true technique to do this.

Platform is IIS6, win2k3, asp.

thanks for any ideas/direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but you will have to put them in a seperate project in visual studio so you can run the as seperate apps.

Comment: how does it get deployed? do they each become unique web sites?

Comment: Yes if you want them running on a different port then set them up as different web sites in IIS, with your web services running on port 8080 or whatever.

Comment: Thats it really? I thought this was going to be more difficult than adding another web site to IIS.

Comment: Nope, easy peasy, just make sure they are separate webb app projects in visual studio.  Its just no different than having multiple websites running on different ports, there is nothing special about web services.

Comment: Okay, well that opens a bunch of more questions. What about hiding or not displaying the WSDL and using SSL?

Comment: Perhaps you should post them as different questions.  SSL will work happily on any port, this article explains how to hide the WSDL using the web.config. http://blog.jonathanroussel.com/2007/04/disabling-aspnet-wsdl-command.html

Comment: Thanks you have been a load of help on this.

Comment: just a quick follow up. Are you saying that the web services can not reference the app_data or app_code folder of the web site then, because the web services are their own web app? This won't work for me if this is the case.

Comment: In terms of the app code folder, you could access the classes in there by referencing the webb app project from the web service app.  However it would be better to set up a class library project, put your classes in there and reference from both web site app and web service app.  I terms of the app data folder, i'm not sure what you mean as i have never found a use for it.  You can access the same database from both projects by simply using the sql database from either app by using the same connections string.

Comment: As a final follow up, I disabled IIS from showing the service folders under the web site URL and allow it under the web service URL all is working perfect now. The added upside now is that I can firewall the ports for internal use only and the services will never show on the public side. thanks again for your input it got me looking in the various places. Didn't have to change much else, always a good thing!!